# I do not see deletd files in recycle bin

Tags: windows-7

I can't see deleted files in the recycle bin. It looks empty but the desktop icon is 'full'.  If I have the recycle bin open when deleting a file I can see it appearing in the bin for two seconds, but after that the file disappears. Are they any solutions to fix it?
Thanks!

I already scanned the computer. No viruses ... everything is OK.

Comment: Thank you! I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Found this site http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/recycle-bin-missing-deleted-files-t381932.html - third post down written by Kelly:

> Files not being listed in the Recycle Bin seem to be related to a corrupt
>   info2 file. To correct the issue (Fat32):
>
> Go to Start/Run and type in CMD:
>
> Type CD \RECYCLED, and then press ENTER.
>   Type ATTRIB -r -s -h info2, and then press ENTER.
>   Type DEL INFO2, and then press ENTER.
>
> NOTE: This deletes the damaged INFO2 file. Windows will recreate this file
>   as needed, automatically.

This may or may not be relevant to your case as she mention FAT32 as partitioning system.

EDIT: she also mentions her own site: http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_qr.htm#rb
with more troubleshooting tips for this problem.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me.